# How to read configuration for a docker-compose from a file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file which looks like below

```
services:
  service1:
    image: image_name:image_tag
    container_name: cname
```

`image_tag` and `cname` can change from deployment to deployment, so I want to have a configuration file (in format of key=value) and read the value of `image_tag` and `cname` from it. How can I fo that?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

You can put an .env file near the docker-compose file. e.g:

.env:

```
image_tag=1.0.0
cname=cname
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  service1:
    image: image_name:${image_tag}
    container_name: ${cname}
```